# Как сделать такую фигуру?

Tags: jquery, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой 6-угольник с бордером и ховер эффектом?

Comment: Откройте сайт в браузере, вызовите магическими пасами инструмент разработчика и спокойно изучайте фигуры

Comment: Проще всего взять две картинки и меня их по псевдоклассу `:hover` Однако, если Вы не ищете легких путей, можете пойти покодить что-то ужасное: [вроде этого](http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bhGn4/) Ну и немного [en:so примеров](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062887/generate-repeating-hexagonal-pattern-with-css3)

Comment: ищите http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=hexagon+&limit=all&type=type-pens   - hexagon, примеров уйма!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
}

/* Base hex */
.hx {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
          align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hexagon {
 width: 110px;
 height: 62px;
 background: #fe635e;
 position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
 position: absolute;
  left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}

.hexagon:before { 
 top: -27px;  
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 28px solid #fe635e;
}
.hexagon:after {
 bottom: -27px; 
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-top: 28px solid #fe635e;
}

/* hex Border */
.hexagon.border {
  width: 120px;
 height: 70px;
  background: #fc8582;
  z-index: 2;
}
.hexagon.border:before {
 top: -30px; 
 border-left: 60px solid transparent;
 border-right: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 30px solid #fc8582;
}
.hexagon.border:after {
 bottom: -30px; 
 border-left: 60px solid transparent;
 border-right: 60px solid transparent;
 border-top: 30px solid #fc8582;
}

/* Icon */
.base span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hover */
.active .base span,
.base:hover span {
  color: #fa6358;
}


.active .base,
.base:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.active .base:before,
.base:hover:before { 
 top: -27px;  
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 28px solid #fff;
}
.active .base:after,
.base:hover:after {
 bottom: -27px; 
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-top: 28px solid #fff;
}

.active .hexagon.border,
.base:hover~.hexagon.border {
  background: #ff625d;
}
.active .hexagon.border:before,
.base:hover~.hexagon.border:before {
 top: -30px; 
 border-left: 60px solid transparent;
 border-right: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 30px solid #ff625d;
}
.active .hexagon.border:after,
.base:hover~.hexagon.border:after {
 bottom: -30px; 
 border-left: 60px solid transparent;
 border-right: 60px solid transparent;
 border-top: 30px solid #ff625d;
}



/* Add other style */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hx-list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
          align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.hx-item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
.hx-title {
  color: #888;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
  .hx-list {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="hx-list">
    <li class="hx-item">
      <div class="hx">
        <div class="hexagon base">
          <span><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="hexagon shadow"></div> -->
        <div class="hexagon border"></div>
      </div>

      <h3 class="hx-title">
        clients
      </h3>
    </li>
    
    <li class="hx-item active">
      <div class="hx">
        <div class="hexagon base">
          <span><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="hexagon shadow"></div> -->
        <div class="hexagon border"></div>
      </div>

      <h3 class="hx-title">
        clients
      </h3>
    </li>
    
    <li class="hx-item">
      <div class="hx">
        <div class="hexagon base">
          <span><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="hexagon shadow"></div> -->
        <div class="hexagon border"></div>
      </div>

      <h3 class="hx-title">
        clients
      </h3>
    </li>
    
    <li class="hx-item">
      <div class="hx">
        <div class="hexagon base">
          <span><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="hexagon shadow"></div> -->
        <div class="hexagon border"></div>
      </div>

      <h3 class="hx-title">
        clients
      </h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Пример на CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/xRdbeV?editors=1100)

Есть разные реализации [Hexagon](http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=hexagon&limit=all&type=type-pens). Один из вариантов, если с `border` - 2 подобные фигуры, наложенные друг на друга.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог!

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов [ссылка](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) :

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#hexagon {
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#hexagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
#hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid red;
}
#inner {
  top: 3px;
  left: 159px;
  width: 83px;
  height: 39px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
#inner:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid green;
}
#inner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid green;
}
#x:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <div id="hexagon"></div>
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделать фигуру и ховер легко, а вот как сделать такой бордер в такой фигуре ????

Comment: @Admiral изменил. можно так, только надо поиграться с размерами...